# How to show full scatter point marker on axis using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, scatter

I am using `matplotlib` to draw a scatter figure. Some of the data is located on the y-axis, but they cannot show full marker.

I have failed to try to use `zorder` to set the order of axis and scatter marker and change the figure size.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Exp = [565, 800, 460, 250, 565]
plt.scatter(np.arange(0, 1.001, 0.25), Exp, c='k', marker='o', label='Exp', s=20.0, zorder=2)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.0, 1.01, 0.2))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.0, 1000.1, 200))
plt.xlim(0, 1.0)
plt.ylim(0, 1000)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I want to show full scatter marker on axis.

Comment: Would changing the `xlim` work? For example `plt.xlim(-0.1, 1.1)`

Comment: Changing `xlim` does work, but the figure does not meet the standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the parameter `clip_on` to `False`. You don't need the `zorder` here. Alternatively, you can increase the x-limits.

```
plt.scatter(np.arange(0, 1.001, 0.25), Exp, c='k', marker='o', label='Exp', 
            s=20.0, clip_on=False)
```

[image]